# Как донести заголовки при редиректе?

Tags: golang

Не получается "донести" заголовки из мидлвари до обработчика

```
func MW(next http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        r.ParseForm()
        redirect := r.FormValue("redirect")
        r.Header.Set("redirect", redirect)
        redir := "http://somedomain/some/path" //RedirectHF обрабатывает этот роут
        // ожидаю, что r внутри Redirect включает в себя заголовок который я установил. Но при попытке получить этот загловок в обработчике дает пустоту
        http.Redirect(w, r, redir, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
    }
}

func RedirectHF(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(r.Header.Get("redirect")) // здесь пусто.
}
```

Помогите пожалуйста. Что не так делаю? Как передать заголовки из мидлвари обработчику?

Comment: Функция [`http.Redirect`](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.22.1:src/net/http/server.go;l=2226) читает из запроса только url для разрешения относительных ссылок в редиректе. Вам следует выставлять необходимые заголовки в `ResponseWriter`.

Comment: @PakUula спасаете как обычно.

Comment: @PakUula Но не работает все равно. В обработчике эндпоинта А, перед редиректом, ставлю заголовок в респонс, делаю редирект на  обработчик Б. В обработчике Б читаю этот заголовок из респонса, там пусто